# Simple? problem, shopping accross 3 shop

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have T product A (irrelevant I know)

in shop 1 I can sell Q product A for Y product B, they possess J number of product B

in shop 2 I can sell W product B for Z product C they possess H number of product C

in shop 3 I can sell  F product C for L product D they possess G number of product D

how much product A should I spend to get the maximum of product D? (how much product A to get a G number of product D)

I've been fiddling round with a pen on my notebook but I can't figure it out.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, without the constraints.

The sentence

> I can sell Q product A for Y product B

establishes a conversion factor between product A and product B that can be summarized in the equation

$number\,sold\,of\,product\,A*\frac{Y}{Q}=number\,recieved\,of\,product\,B$

Similarly the conversion factor from product B to C is

$number\,sold\,of\,product\,B*\frac{Z}{W}=number\,recieved\,of\,product\,C$

and finally from C to D is

$number\,sold\,of\,product\,C*\frac{L}{F}=number\,recieved\,of\,product\,D$

So, assuming all the shops had enough product, going from shop to shop converting one product to the next could be represented by stringing together all the conversion factors. This gives us the direct conversion of A to D:

$number\,sold\,of\,product\,A*(\frac{Y}{Q}*\frac{Z}{W}*\frac{L}{F})=number\,recieved\,of\,product\,D$

Which is a straightforward linear relationship. To get out the most D put in the most A.

And if you want out a specific number of product D, say G, then plug G in and divide by the conversion factor. Which looks like

$number\,sold\,of\,product\,A=\frac{G}{\frac{Y}{Q}*\frac{Z}{W}*\frac{L}{F}}=G*(\frac{Q*W*F}{Y*Z*L})$

Now, to consider the fact that the shops have a limited supply of each product.

This may or may not be a problem. In order to figure out if it is or not you should use the conversion factors to figure out how much of product D you would get if you were to take the absolute maximum at each store.

so

$store\, 1\,max=J*\frac{Z}{W}*\frac{L}{F}$

$store\, 2\,max=H*\frac{L}{F}$

and the max of store three is already in terms of product D, it's just $G$

If our original conversion of A to D (namely, $number\,of\,product\,A*(\frac{Y}{Q}*\frac{Z}{W}*\frac{L}{F})$) is below all of those constraints then it means that the stores will have enough product to accommodate all of our trading. However, if our original conversion is larger than one or more of the constraints then we have more product than that store can handle, and so our final amount of product D will be that smallest constraint.